# CentOS 7 : MariaDB service: Fails to start

Tags: mariadb, centos7

MariaDB service is not starting, mariadb.service file was created by the system. Status check shows the below error. We have provided 777 permission for the library but still the service throws this error. The DB Server (5.5.65) runs fine when we run mysqld_safe directly.

```
mariadb-prepare-db-dir[22847]: sed: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

Please let us know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: could you please share output of **ls -ld /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1** and **ls -ld /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1** once.

Comment: Rohit, thanks for your reply. This is the output - $ls -ld /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Apr 28  2020 /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 -> libpcre.so.1.2.0

$ls -ld /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1
ls: cannot access /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so.1: No such file or directory

Comment: But but your question made me look at the permissions of libpcre.so.1.2.0. That was the problem - $ls -ld /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
-rwxrwx--- 4 freeswitch daemon 402384 Aug  2  2017 /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0

Comment: Fixed its permission and now mariadb is starting fine. Thanks Rohit !

Comment: great. see.. libpcre.so.1 is softlink of libpcre.so.1.2.0 so We should have required permission on source as well.